# Javascript code not running when inside a function

Tags: javascript

I am making a game in html and javascript and have used a 'console' I used IF statements to allow the user to navigate around the game. But, they have seemed to stop working. They allow the user to move around in the game. Why aren't the IF statements running and how can I fix this?

```js
function runcmd(){
 var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
 if(user == 'clear'){
  l1.innerHTML = '';
  l2.innerHTML = '';
  l3.innerHTML = '';
  l4.innerHTML = '';
  l5.innerHTML = '';
  l6.innerHTML = '';
  l7.innerHTML = '';
  l8.innerHTML = '';
  l9.innerHTML = '';
  l10.innerHTML = '';
 };
 if(user == 'connect'){
  var user = document.getElementById('code').value;
  l1.innerHTML = 'Connecting to ' ;
  l2.innerHTML = 'Connected to ' ;
  connected = true;
  l4.innerHTML = 'view bank';
  l5.innerHTML = 'upload [virus]';
  l8.innerHTML = 'disconnect [ip]';
  if(user == 'disconnect'){
   connected = false;
   l1.innerHTml = 'Disconnected Safely...';
  };
  if(user == 'view bank'){
   var pwrd = Math.floor( Math.random() * 1) - 10000;
   var nam = Math.floor( Math.random() * 1) - 10000;
   alert(pwrd);
      alert(nam);
   var uname = 'user' + nam;
   var user = prompt('Username: ');
   var pass = prompt('Password: ');
   if(user == uname && pass == pwrd ){
   }
  }; 
  if(user == 'upload'){
      svirus= prompt('Enter Virus: ');
   for(var key in boughtviruses) {
    if(boughtviruses[key] == svirus) {
     l1.innerHTML = 'Uploading ' + svirus;
     l2.innerHTML = 'Virus Uploaded';
    }else{
     alert("You Don't Have This Virus!");
     };
            };
  };
 };
};
```

```css
   .console{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-left: 10px solid #cccccc;
    border-top: 5px solid #cccccc;
    border-right: 10px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #cccccc;
   }
   .exit {
    float: right;
    background: #800000;
    color: white;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
   }
```

```html
   <div id="con" class="console">
    <button class="exit" onclick="hidecon()">X</button>
     <span class="span" id="l1" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l2" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l3" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l4" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l5" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l6"  style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l7" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l8" style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l9"  style="width:50px"></span><br />
     <span class="span" id="l10"  style="width:50px"></span><br />
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;color:#66ff33;">C:\></span><input onclick="this.select()" id="code" class="inp"/>
    <button style="border:none;position:absolute;background-color:black;bottom:0;right:114;color:#66ff33;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid white;" onclick="runcmd()">Send Command</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: doesn't run as in, what are you expecting ?

Comment: what is `user`,`uname`,`pass` and `pwrd` ?

Comment: _"doesn't seem to run"_ What is expected result? How would user be aware of exact random number set at `nam` or `pwrd`?

Comment: @were matrix generating user name at random will generate duplicate someday

Comment: works totally fine , hope you are providing user user-10000 and password -10000

Comment: @were matrix , the code is not in the right order, I have put it below

Comment: I have edited the question as i have realized that none of the code in the function works

Comment: Will never work ,if you are inserting the alerted username and password, the code is in wrong order, var nam = Math.floor( Math.random() * 1) - 10000;
   alert(pwrd);
      alert(nam);
   var uname = 'user' + nam;
   var user = prompt('Username: ');
   var pass = prompt('Password: ');
   if(user == uname && pass == pwrd ){
   }   to this     alert(pwrd);
     
   var uname = 'user' + nam; alert(nam);
   var user = prompt('Username: ');
   var pass = prompt('Password: ');
   if(user == uname && pass == pwrd ){
   }

Answer (score 1):

Working perfectly when u enter '-10000' for password and 'user-10000' for username

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to create username & password via generating random integers.

The problem with your solution is, as `Math.random()` will always have values between 0 & 1, applying `Math.floor()` to it will always provide the value `0`.

So, your usernames and password will always have `-10000` value, which is something I believe you do not want.

Instead, try doing `Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)` which will give you random integer in the range of `1000` to `10000`.